# Why does Idris order the arguments to Data.Vect as size then item-type?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

Just as the title says. In the other dependent systems I'm familiar with (Agda and Coq), the vector type is defined as `Vect : Type -> Nat -> Type`. Putting the parameters before the indexes makes sense to me and, in any case, it seems to be the standard for the vector type. Why does Idris use `Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no observable difference in Idris between parameters and indices. Having the type parameter the last one is convenient for the `Functor (Vect n)` instance.

Comment: For interface instances! Ha! Yes, that makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Some time ago Idris used `Vect : Type -> Nat -> Type`, but it was changed in this [commit](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/commit/61d39dabbf63237671a9661064e6b0478add62e4) with the following commit message: "Swapped Vect arguments.
So now nicer to write type class instances for Functor, Applicative, etc".